# Flink java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm using Kafka as data source for Flink job. When I'm deploying job to flink cluster job manager I'm receiving an error ClassNotFoundException: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource`

Below is my pom.xml dependancies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Create an uber jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flink itself does not contain these extension JAR files (u can find jar file in flink/lib ), If you do not enter these jars into your project's JAR file(uber jar), or specify them when submitting the task (see the Flink documentation), flink runtime will not find these Jars.

Answer (score -1):

Flink connector is not under the flink classpath by default, you need to add the kafka connector maven dependency into your project

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.